# javascript charCodeAt - different values in JsFiddle and in local file

Tags: javascript, unicode

This line, when saved in a local html file, alerts 229:

```
<script>alert("基".charCodeAt(0))</script>
```

But when the alert is copied to JSFiddle, it provides 22522.

Why is there a difference?

Comment: In which charset you saved this line in a file?

Comment: the charset is utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because JSFiddle charset is `utf-8`

You will need to set the right charset inside your `meta` tag inside your `head` tags.

With the following meta tag it will show `22522` and without it will show `229`:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Please check the following Links:

[ref_html_utf8](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp)

[html_charset](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)

Tested in local file with HTML looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>alert("基".charCodeAt(0))</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```