# Encode String to HEX

Tags: javascript, utf-8, hex

i have my function to convert string to hex:

```
function encode(str){
    str = encodeURIComponent(str).split('%').join('');
    return str.toLowerCase();
}
```

example:

`守护村子`

`alert(encode('守护村子'));`

the output would be:

`e5ae88e68aa4e69d91e5ad90`

It works on Chinese characters. But when i do it with English letters

`alert(encode('Hello World'))`;

it outputs:

`hello20world`

I have tried this for converting string to hex:

```
function String2Hex(tmp) {
    var str = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        str += tmp[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    }
    return str;
}
```

then tried it on the  Chinese characters above, but it outputs the UTF-8 HEX:

`5b8862a467515b50`

not the ANSI Hex:

`e5ae88e68aa4e69d91e5ad90`

I also have searched converting UFT8 to ANSI but no luck.
Anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex). I think it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks but it is not the answer, it is similar to the `String2Hex` function above, that gives the utf8 hex code, not ansi hex code. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Try converting the text to latin1 using `tmp = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Unicode string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by downloading `utf8.js`

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js

then using the `String2Hex` function from above:

```js
alert(String2Hex(utf8.encode('守护村子')));
```

It gives me the output I want:

`e5ae88e68aa4e69d91e5ad90`

Comment: Anyone looking at this question like me should also consider the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965971/javascript-charcodeat-different-values-in-jsfiddle-and-in-local-file

Comment: anyone looking for answer without third part can refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex)

Comment: This answer isn't really self contained. It relies entirely on an external resource...

Answer (score 26):

As a self-contained solution in functional style, you can encode with:

```
plain.split("")
     .map(c => c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
     .join("");
```

The `split` on an empty string produces an array with one character (or rather, one UTF-16 codepoint) in each element. Then we can map each to a HEX string of the character code.

Then to decode:

```
hex.split(/(\w\w)/g)
   .filter(p => !!p)
   .map(c => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16)))
   .join("")
```

This time the regex passed to `split` captures groups of two characters, but this form of `split` will intersperse them with empty strings (the stuff "between" the captured groups, which is nothing!). So `filter` is used to remove the empty strings. Then `map` decodes each character.

Comment: @rumpel true! I’ve added a `padStart`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it works in modern browsers and node and does not require additional libraries.

Comment: Hmm... "fromCharCode" returns anything in between 0 and 65535, and to encode it properly you need 4 hex characters, not 2, right? Don't think this answer will work for any strings containing non-ASCII characters...

Answer (score 24):

On Node.js, you can do:

```js
const myString = "This is my string to be encoded/decoded";
const encoded = Buffer.from(myString).toString('hex'); // encoded == 54686973206973206d7920737472696e6720746f20626520656e636f6465642f6465636f646564
const decoded = Buffer.from(encoded, 'hex').toString(); // decoded == "This is my string to be encoded/decoded"
```

Comment: FYI: The `Buffer` class is not standardized by any standards body I know of, including ECMA. It *is* offered by Node.js, however, and does what you'd think it does.

Comment: **Doesn't work in browsers.** Not only isn't it standardized like amn says, but also it just doesn't exist, it's only a Node.js thing unfortunately. This means it doesn't answer the question because, obviously, alert() as OP used in the question doesn't make sense in Node.js, they clearly meant for this to work in a browser. But hopefully it still helps others that want to use this in server-side code...

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```js
var str="some random string";
var result = "";
for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    hex = str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    result += ("000"+hex).slice(-4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to properly handle UTF8 strings you can try these:

```js
function utf8ToHex(str) {
  return Array.from(str).map(c => 
    c.charCodeAt(0) < 128
      ? c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
      : encodeURIComponent(c).replace(/\%/g,'').toLowerCase()
  ).join('');
}

function hexToUtf8(hex) {
  return decodeURIComponent('%' + hex.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('%'));
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lyquix/k2tjbrvq/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```js
function toHex(txt){
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    return Array
        .from(encoder.encode(txt))
        .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
        .join('')
}
```